# How can I place "WHERE CLAUSE " to this query in order to filter a results

Tags: mysql, pivot

This is mysql query that found on the internet and modified to my needs, but I failed to place where clause in order to filter result.

```
SELECT 
stid, 
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'MATH' THEN marks END) MATH ,
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'HIST' THEN marks END) HIST,
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'SCI' THEN marks END) SCI,
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'GEO' THEN marks END) GEO,
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'ENG' THEN marks END) ENG,
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'CIV' THEN marks END) CIV,
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'VS' THEN marks END) VS, 
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'KISW' THEN marks END) KISW 
FROM finalresults 
GROUP BY stid ORDER BY 1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between `FROM` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
stid, 
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'MATH' THEN marks END) MATH ,
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'HIST' THEN marks END) HIST,
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'SCI' THEN marks END) SCI,
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'GEO' THEN marks END) GEO,
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'ENG' THEN marks END) ENG,
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'CIV' THEN marks END) CIV,
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'VS' THEN marks END) VS, 
MAX( CASE WHEN courseid = 'KISW' THEN marks END) KISW 
FROM finalresults 
WHERE field=value
GROUP BY stid
ORDER BY 1
```